# Restlet with Jetty connector example/configuration

Tags: java, maven, restlet

I would like to configure [Restlet](https://restlet.com/) via web.xml to use jetty connector.
I guess I'm missing some information and not finding those in their documentation page, please provide a working example/configuration how to get Restlet with jetty connector working together.

I already added the extension ( org.restlet.ext.jetty ) to pom.xml, and here is my current web.xml configuration:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
         <display-name>TestService</display-name>
         <servlet>
                 <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
                 <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
                 <init-param>
                         <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
                         <param-value>com.test.main.Server</param-value>
                 </init-param>
         </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: are you getting error or warning? If you are getting, pls share it.

Comment: No..
I'm asking for a help to get Restlet working with jetty connector that's all.

Answer (score 0):

in your  tags you had defined init param. Try to define another init param tag in it and put configuration at below.I think that is your missing part.

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.clients</param-name>
        <param-value>HTTP HTTPS FILE</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Please take a look at this link. I hope that your problem has been resolved.

https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/user-guide/2.3/editions/jee/client-connectors

Comment: See https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/user-guide/2.3/core/base/connectors, and https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/user-guide/2.3/extensions/jetty those the connectors I'm referring to.

Comment: could you pls share with me the url that you are using for request from server?

Comment: You are asking for unneeded information, all I want is how to configure jetty connector.